# Activate logout security configuration

Tags: symfony, sonata

I have this problem, I changed the place of the logout configuration in the firewall but always the same response, what should I do ?

I get this error :

> You must activate the logout in your security firewall configuration

This is my code

```
security:
    firewalls:
        oauth_authorize:
            pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/auth
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                check_path: _security_check
                login_path: _demo_login
        oauth_token:
            pattern:    ^/oauth/v2/token
            security:   false
        api:
            pattern:    ^/api
            fos_oauth:  true
            stateless:  true
            anonymous:  false # can be omitted as its default value
        login:
            pattern:  ^/secured/login$
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path: /profile
        logout:
            path: /user/logout
            anonymous: true
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        admin:
            pattern:            /admin(.*)
            context:            user
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /admin/login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /admin/login_check
                failure_path:   null
            logout:
                path:           /admin/logout
            anonymous:          true
        main:
            pattern:             .*
            context:             user
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /login_check
                failure_path:   null
            logout:             true
            anonymous:          true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem and it works , the problem was in the main configuration

```
 main:      
    pattern: ^/
    security: true
    switch_user: true
    form_login:
        provider: fos_userbundle
        csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        default_target_path: /profile
        anonymous:    true
    logout:
        path:   /logout
        target: /login
        invalidate_session: true
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps try this :

```
dev:
    pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
    security: false

main:
    pattern: ^/
    security: true
    switch_user: true
    form_login:
        provider: fos_userbundle
        csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        success_handler: fo_security.handler.login_success
        default_target_path: /
    anonymous:    true
    logout:
        path:   /logout
        target: /login
        invalidate_session: true
```

If you don't use the FOSUserBundle don't attention of parameter for this.
This example try 3 things :

- declare the dev firewall before
- declare logout differently and invalidate session
- when you logout you immediatly redirect on login page

Comment: I try it but it doesn't work , the error is "The service "security.firewall.map.context.main" has a dependency on a non-existent service "fos_security.handler.login_success". I deleted the "success_handler: fos_security.handler.login_success" and the same first error  "You must activate the logout in your security firewall configuration"

Comment: i change the code and now i have this problem No route found for "GET /" (from ...../web/app_dev.php/admin/dashboard")